# Having some problems with conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So I have two sheets together and I'm trying to change the colour of a cell in one sheet based on if a range in the other sheet contains a certain value.

For example, in sheet 1 I would like cell A1 to turn red if the word "cat" occurs in a cell in the range A1:A20 in sheet 2.

I feel like this should be possible, but I'm not certain. Thanks for any help.

Edit: I was able to get the sheet1 cell to turn colour if a specific cell in sheet2 has the right word using =INDIRECT("Sheet2!A3")="cat". I tried changing the A3 to A1:A20 to search that range for the word cat but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

You can format cells depending on whether the range `Sheet2!A1:A20` contains `cat` with a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule like this:

`=counta( iferror( filter( indirect("Sheet2!A1:A20"), indirect("Sheet2!A1:A20") = "cat") ) )`